# Can Google Assistant access audio on a web post

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to allow my friend using Google Home to access audio posts on a WordPress blog.  Can I make it treat my blog as a podcast without registering it with, say, iTunes?

I don't have a Google Home unit, and have not found detailed documentation on Google Assistant, except for writing actions.  Is there a simpler way to do what I want without writing an action?  Can I get my audio file and then access the existing code that handles operations within a file such as seeking, play, pause, etc. from my action?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [content actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/podcasts) to generate a unique feed for your audio posts. In this way, you would be able to effectively create a podcast which can be surfaced by users on Google Homes as well in the [Google Podcasts app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.podcasts). This would be a shallow integration.

If you want something more advanced and customized, you can create an Action and make use of the [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) in Actions on Google.

Even if you don't have a Google Home, you are able to access your Action from other surfaces like a smartphone. You can also make use of the [simulator](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/simulator) in the Actions on Google console for development.